# Win 7 says it cannot create a restore point in safe mode, but it isn't in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, windows, system-restore

in7 64-bit, just had the repair shop put in a new disk (ssd is nice), reinstall windows, etc.  Now I want to create a restore point.  Windows says it cannot create a restore point in safe mode.  I've rebooted several times, and I'm not in safe mode.

Poking around in various fora, I found a suggestion that I check the bootup (normal limited etc.); it was normal.  I found that two services -- Volume Shadow Copy and Windows Installer are both supposed to be running; they were stopped, so I set them to automatic and rebooted again.  No change in creating a restore point, and I did check that they are running now.

I use BitDefender AV 2015; I ran a full system scan.  It found and corrected two registry ad-looking things.  I rebooted and tried again, no change.  I uninstalled BitDefender, same result.

Can someone tell me how to fix this, or at least somewhere else to look?

--edit

bcdedit output, as requested.

[image]

Comment: I uninstalled BitDefender and rebooted as it suggested.  Same result.  I suppose I should have said that I have used restore points before with BitDefender installed, couldn't imagine that was the problem.  But now we know.

Comment: Is there other vital information I need to include?

Comment: What does `BCDEDIT` have to say? Could you provide the output from that command in your question? You will need to run that from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: Also just to be sure, run this command as well I suppose: `bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot`. Alternatively, you could also try running [this command](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20603742/17681410): `if /i "%SAFEBOOT_OPTION%"=="MINIMAL" echo We're in Safe Mode!`